# Alignment Issue with IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am somewhat of a newbie but I am working on building a site and I have a div that does not center in IE11 but is fine with firefox. any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried putting in my code but it won't let me post the code because of a formatting error. What I have is a table with linked pictures that get larger when the mouse is over them and reduce in size when the mouse is off. This is making the div below it move when they change size. I set the table to absolute which worked on firefox but in IE is shifted to the left. I tried auto margin on both sides, pushing it left with padding, text-align to center, position 0 auto etc. I am not sure what else to do. is this a known problem or is it just me? here is my css

my css

```
        table{

  display:inline; 
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:235px;

}


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Home | Babylon</title>
 <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tabLogo.ico.ico"/>

 </head>

 <body>

 <h1>Babylon</h1>

<div class="slider">
```

```
<div class="table">
<table>  
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><a href="living_rooms.html"><img src="images/home page photos/f3497310.jpg" alt="Living Rooms"/><br/><br/>Living Rooms</a></td>
  <td><a href="bedrooms.html"><img src="images/home page photos/f2172167.jpg" alt="Dining Rooms"/><br/><br/>Dining Rooms</a></td>
  <td><a href="bedrooms.html"><img src="images/home page photos/f9157.jpg" alt="Bedrooms"/><br/><br/>Bedrooms</a></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
  <td><a href="futons.html"><img src="images/home page photos/f7011130.jpg" alt="Futons"/><br/><br/>Futons</a></td>
  <td><a href="desk_shelves_and_more.html"><img src="images/home page photos/f4494.jpg" alt="Desks, Shelves and more"/><br/><br/>Desks, Shelves and more</a></td>
  <td><a href="rugs.html"><img src="images/home page photos/714-BLACKa.jpg" alt="Rugs"/><br/><br/>Rugs</a></td>   
</tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Select your code and press Ctrl+K to format it. Code will help us understand your problem better

Comment: Sorry I am new here but I got it figured out and posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Your div is unclosed.

And do a `text-align: center` on the parent element, and look if it works without the table class.